# How to manage the native heap?

Tags: java, android

I'm researching about lazy list, and i have a concern about it

When the native heap is too lager, how can we detect and control it (clearing or reset all count ... ) ??

Please, help me :(!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onLowMemory` callback of your activity to handle that...